# How to move from an activity back to navigation drawer

Tags: android, fragment

First I create app of Navigation Drawer Activity and travel from fragment to new activity, Now I want to set Home Button on New activity which navigates to main activity of navigation drawer. I tried to use this code:

```
btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(add_activity.this,MainFragment.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

But there shows an error as Unfortunately your app has stopped

Comment: Include your logcat!  There is not enough information here for anyone to answer your question

Comment: Natural task backstack ordering should just take you back? Use a diagram, or textural flow of what you want to happen.

Comment: All right just forget about the error. Please can you tell what kind of code is needed to take me from an activity to navigation drawer and is the above code correct?

Answer (score 0):

We need more details in order to help you.
First thing i've noted was this line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(add_activity.this,MainFragment.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
```

Problem with this is that you can't start fragments with Intent.

If you want to start *TravelActivity* from *MainActivity* do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this /*indicating your current activity*/, TravelActivity.class /*indicating Activity you want to start*/)
startActivity(intent); //start TravelActivity
finish() //finish current activity - if you press back you will exit the app (if MainActivity was launcher activity)
```

If you have fragment that should be loaded when Travel activity is started following is a simple helper method that will do the fragment transaction for you

```
public void replaceFragment(int rootViewId, Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
    try {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (fragment == null)
            return;
        if (checkIfFragmentIsCurrent(fragment, rootViewId))
            return;

        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
        boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

        if (!fragmentPopped) {

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(rootViewId, fragment);

            if (addToBackStack) {
                transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
            transaction.commit();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ReplaceFragment", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

protected boolean checkIfFragmentIsCurrent(Fragment fragment, int placeHolderRes) {
    Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(placeHolderRes);
    if (fragment != null && currentFragment != null) {
        if (fragment.getClass().equals(currentFragment.getClass())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In order to use this just call replacFragment(ID of container that will hold your fragment, Fragment instance, true - if you want to add fragment to the backStack)

To understand fragment transactions reffer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)